# Cambiar de Mac el iPhone Certificado de Distribución

Tags: xcode, iphone, itunes-connect

Soy nuevo en el desarrollo de aplicaciones para la app Store.
Hace poco tuve que desarrollar un par de aplicaciones y las publiqué, el problema es que dentro de poco tendré que cambiar de Mac para desarrollar y necesitaré segur actualizando las aplicaciones. 
Según yo lo necesario es exportar el certificado (el .p12) de distribución que solicité y usé para publicar las aplicaciones.
¿Basta con instalar ese certificado en la nueva Mac y los provisioning profile de cada aplicaciones y debería de poder continuar trabajando desde otro equipo?

Otra cuestión es que en el llavero aparecen varios certificados de iPhone pero que no son de distribución. ¿Esos habría que considerarlos también?
Saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es más fácil, en el mac viejo vas a

> Xcode -> preferencias -> cuentas

en el engrane de abajo viene la opción exportar apple id y firmas de código, te pedirá contraseña para guardar. Y en el nuevo mac lo importas usando la opción importar. Saludos

Comment: Pero una vez hecho eso, no necesitaría los .p12?
Al exportarlo me genera un .developerprofile, y solicita una contraseña. Imagino que de querer instalarlo más adelante en otro equipo sólo se ingresa el password y debería de aparecer las cuentas en el Xcode. Pero en sí, el certificado de distribución y los provisioning profile ya no harían falta?

Comment: En teoría el exportar las firmas de código te va exportar los certificados instalados en el acceso a llaveros... puedes hacer la prueba para que veas,  los certificados de distribución son solo a la hora de firmar la app, para futuras apps necesitaras actualizar cada certificado, Xcode ya lo hace automáticamente por lo que en mi experiencia es suficiente exportar lo que te mencioné.